# How to fix input paddig in HTML5

Tags: css, html

I have a problem with padding in HTML5. I'm using this code:

```
input[type="password"] {
border: 1px solid #CECECE;
border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
padding: 7px;
font-size: 1em;
outline: none;
width: 100%;
margin: 0px;}
```

I use inputs in div, which has padding 10px.
And when I'm testing code the width of input is not right, look at this pic:
How to solve this problem? I want to have padding 10px in any window size.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this CSS :

```
input {
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

This property will include padding and border to the width/height of inputs so they won't overflow anymore.

Comment: Add also -webkit-box-sizing: border-box for Chrome/Safari older versions. http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/ - Also the order should be prefix browser versions first than the non-prefixed.

Comment: I'm always adding -webkit and -moz options to my code :)

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
box-sizing:border-box;
-moz-box-sizing:border-box;
```

in your css file.

```
input[type="password"] {
    border: 1px solid #CECECE;
    border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
    padding: 7px;
    font-size: 1em;
    outline: none;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/* apply a natural box layout model to all elements */
*, *:before, *:after {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;
 }
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/yTM9U/2/

Answer (score -1):

You need to set the CSS style `margin-right` for the input.

```
input {
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Padding is a cushioning/space inside the element. To push an element away from 
surrounding elements internal cushioning/padding-space cannot help. Margin needs
to be set for those purposes...

But in your case, r/l to the form width, inputs are already very wide (100%). So, you need to decrease the width of the inputs. Try

```
input {
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 90%;
}
```